# Name der Eigenschaft der deutschen Sprache, viele bedeutungsverwandte Wörter mit demselben Stamm zu bilden

Tags: single-word-request, semantics, morphology

Wie heißt die Eigenschaft der deutschen Sprache, viele bedeutungsverwandte Wörter mit demselben Wortstamm zu bilden?

Das klassische Beispiel ist *Schlüssel, Schloß, schließen, verschließen* – im Französischen *clé, serrure, fermer, fermer à clé/obturer*, im Englischen *key, lock, close, lock/seal*.

Ich habe einmal einen linguistischen Terminus dafür gelesen, ihn aber vergessen.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass die französische und englische Morphologie hier signifikant unproduktiver ist bzw. war als die deutsche. _Derivation_ und [_Konversion_](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konversion_(Linguistik)) könnten gemeint sein, passen aber nicht ganz.

Comment: Suchst du tatsächlich ein Wort, dass eine Eigenschaft der deutschen Sprache angibt (also etwas, das Deutsch von z.B. Englisch und Französisch unterscheidet), oder geht es um eine Eigenschaft bestimmter Wortstämme? Die gesucht Eigenschaft der Wortstämme wäre nämlich »produktiv«.

Comment: Produktivität kam mir auch in den Sinn, aber die Wörterbuchdefinition passt nicht zu dem Beispiel. Ich vermute, eine gewisse typologische Klasse sei gemeint, etwa Fusional, doch da besteht auch kein wirklicher Unterschied zu Französisch. Drittens denke ich an Polysemy. Gut möglich, dass OP die Sache einfach nicht richtig darstellt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Es geht mir um eine Eigenschaft, die das Deutsche vom Englischen und Deutschen unterscheidet.

Comment: @vectory: Was könnte ich nicht richtig dargestellt haben? Die Behauptung ist, dass es viele Beispiele wie das vom Schließen gibt, was das Deutsche vom Englischen und Französischen unterscheidet. Wenn das nicht so wäre, dann hätte ich etwas falsch dargestellt. "Produktiv" trifft es nicht, denn produktiv sind alle Sprachen.